# This prime factorization code works for small numbers but fails with an OutOfMemoryException for large numbers?

Tags: f#, primes, ml

I'm trying to get the prime factors for a large number..

```
let factors (x:int64) =
  [1L..x]
  |> Seq.filter(fun n ->  x%n = 0L)

let isPrime (x:int64) = 
 factors x
 |> Seq.length = 2

let primeFactors (x:int64)= 
 factors x 
 |> Seq.filter isPrime
```

This works for say 13195 but fails with an OutOfMemoryException for 600851475143?

Sorry if i'm missing something obvious, it's only my third day on F# and I didn't know what a prime factor was until this morning.

Comment: What seems to be your problem? An `OutOfMemoryException` is a normal result of using large amounts of memory like you're doing.

Comment: An observation: to compute the factors of a number you only need to go up to `sqrt x`, not `x`.

Comment: @mydogisbox do you think an OutOfMemoryException is the desired result?

Comment: Of course not.  You haven't explained what your problem is though.  You've simply described the behavior of the code sample.  Are you wanting a way to avoid the OOM exception with your current code?  Are you wanting a different way of solving the problem altogether?  Are you wanting an explanation of why you got an OOM exception?  Describe what information you're looking for and we can give you an explanation.  Otherwise we're simply guessing at what you want.

Comment: @mydogisbox it's pretty obvious I'd like to avoid the exception and find out which part of the code is causing it.

Comment: @LeeSmith It may be obvious to you, but its not obvious to me.  The fact that `[1L..x]` is causing the oom exception is obvious to be because of my experience, but I can't know if its obvious to you unless you're explicit about what your problem is.

Comment: @mydogisbox: The problem is already explicit.  See my edit to the title.

Answer (score 5):

The expresion `[1L..x]` creates a list, which in your example gets too large to be stored in memory.

Sequences in contrast are lazy, so if used with care you can avoid computing the whole intermediate list. Your code already uses sequences but as said before it begins with a list, to avoid converting from a list you can use curly brackets: `{1L..x}`

Using sequence expressions is another option:

```
let factors (x:int64) = seq {
    for i = 1L to x do
        if x%i = 0L then yield i}
```

Having solved the `OutOfMemoryException` problem your prime function is very slow, you can optimise it as suggested in the comments by returning `false` immediately after finding a divisor between 1 and its square root. Further optimisations may be achieved by dividing the number by the prime factors as you find them and using a sieve for the primes, you can also have a look at some efficient algorithms [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

The expression `[...]` creates a list of the items specified.  In F#, a `List` can be defined something like this:

```
type List<'t> = 
    | empty
    | item of 't * List<'t>
```

As an example, `[1..5]' would become a structure looking like this:

```
item(1, item(2, item(3, item(4, item(5, empty)))))
```

As you can see, this will not be a problem for small numbers of items, but for larger numbers of items this will eventually use up all the available memory and cause an `OutOfMemoryExcepion`.  As Gustavo mentioned, to avoid this, you can use a sequence, which will create each item on demand rather than all at the beginning.  This reduces the number of things in memory at one time and thus avoids an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Since you're already using the `Seq` module instead of the `List` module (i.e. `Seq.filter` vs `List.filter` etc), you can simply use a sequence instead of a list which would look like this: `{1L..x}`.